# Use responsive background image without set it's height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I have this code:

```
.header {
    background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=86&txt=1800%C3%97345&w=1800&h=345');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

I want that the background image will be responsive without mention it's height (unlike the code above).
I tried to set the `height` to `100%` or `auto` but it doesn't work.

My question is how can I make that background responsive without mention it's height?

Comment: Do you mean the height will based on the content inside the header? as long it's not empty, it would be fine. Otherwise, the header might be just zero height.

Comment: @Pangloss There is no content inside the header, only the background image

Comment: And what are you expecting? apart from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're using it you can use

`max-width: 100%;` or `width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

You can't really ignore the height, but you can work around it.

as @Isaac Madwed says, you may define a `max-width`, but you may also use an automatic height.

The height attribute has a value of `auto` by default, but if you are using a pre-made theme or template, this value may have been reset to something different.

Thus, you not only guarantee that the image will not overflow from the right, but also that the height of the image gets proportional to the actual width.

The resulting CSS can be something like:

```
.header {
    background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=86&txt=1800%C3%97345&w=1800&h=345');
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Optionally, you may want to set a `min-width` in order to ensure that the image looks nice on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

See example at http://jsfiddle.net/o0g3qsev/.